# Google cloud sql is not connected to mysql client

Tags: mysql, sql, google-cloud-sql

Google cloud `sql` is not connected to `mysql` client and its giving Error.

```
Error 2005 : Unknown Mysql Server Host '--user=root'
```

But google cloud `sql` is connected to `Mysql` workbench.

I have used the command to connect to `mysql` client.

```
mysql> connect --host:111.11.11.11 --user=root --password=123456
```

And its also not connected to `mysql` through google app engine Application.
When connected google cloud `sql` then its giving unknown Error

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have a colon (`:`) in your connect command. Launch the MySQL client like this:

```
mysql --host=11.11.11.11 --user=root --password=123456
```

Documentation on how to connect to be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connecting.html)

Comment: Yes i have used  mysql> connect --host=111.11.11.11 --user=root --password=123456   still there is error Unknown Mysql server host

Comment: Did you start the mysql client with the host, user, and password flags? It looks like you're trying to run the "connect" command inside mysql client.